# jQuery Validation on Dynamically created controls

Tags: jquery

I'm using an ASP.NET Repeater control to create rows of textboxes.  I'm able to capture the value of the textboxes, but I would like to validate that all the textboxes have a value inside.

Is this possible to do in jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sure it is.**

```
$(".submit-button").click(function() {
    $("class-or-id-of-repeater").find("input[type=text]").each(function() {
        if($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
            alert("At least one textbox is empty");
            $(this).focus(); // focus the element
        }
    })
});
```

If you create Dynamic Controls in ASP.NET, the textboxes will still be rendered on the page after the postback.

I haven't tested this using an UpdatePanel, it might break if you used one.

Comment: Your code didn't initially work for me because the Repeater tag isn't generated as part of the markup when rendered in the browser, so I wrapped the Repeater control into a DIV.  Then your code worked!!  Thanks alot!!